# Location of /dev/shm on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, shared-memory

I am working on a shared memory assignment on Mac OS X

```
    #define SHARED_OBJECT_PATH    "/my_shared_memory"

    fd = shm_open(SHARED_OBJECT_PATH, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
    if (fd < 0) {                                                         
        perror("In shm_open()");                                          
        exit(1);                                                          
    }
```

One of the small snippets in the program is the above.

When I compile and run the program a second time, I would get the error:

`In shm_open(): File exists`

I am assuming because I need to manually delete using `rm [path_to]/my_shared_memory`. I know on Linux, the default location is `/dev/shm`, however, this path does not exist on Mac OS X.

Where is the location of `my_shared_memory` so I can delete it?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution to your problem is not using

```
O_EXCL
```

if you don't want that behaviour.

Generally, shared memory objects do have a name, but it's not really a file name -- you can't generally delete them. It's good POSIX style to display them under /dev/shm, but this depends on your OS:

My best guess would be that you should read what `man shm_open` says on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Under Mac OS which is derived from BSD, there are no visible file entries in the file system for shared memory objects. Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73752984/14393739 for more details.
As a consequence, it is not possible to do cleanups with a `rm` command or `unlink()` call. **O_EXCL** flag should be used with care: at program startup, try `shm_open()` without **O_EXCL** and **O_CREAT** first. If the latter fails, retry with both flags.